# Why is 1 ^ 1 = 0 in C

Tags: c, gcc, gnu

In this code

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
    int i = 1, j = 0;

    printf("%d", i ^ !j);

    return 0;
}
```

The result of this code is **0** instead of 1 even if **i = 1 and j = 1**.

How does it work ?

Comment: Because `^` is a `XOR` operation and not power.

Comment: thx! got it....

Comment: Sure.
I understand now there is no exponentiation in C using operator (^).
So, if you want to use power operator you have to use it mathematically.
This confusion raised because I got to use Java, C++, PHP and others and I just started to use C.

Thanks for your support.

Comment: @Saif `^` is also the XOR operator in C++, Java and PHP. Since when did you got used to those languages?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^` is bitwise exclusive or in C, not exponentiation.  So when you flip all the set bits of 1 in 1, you get 0.